# What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site for questions about SketchUp?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I post questions I have related to using [Google SketchUp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SketchUp)?

Comment: What **kind** of questions? At first glance, Superuser, but if you are developing an extension or script for Sketchup, perhaps Stack Overflow would be suitable.

Comment: The [Graphics Design beta site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) has some indication of Sketchup questions being welcome, but how welcome I don't know. Figure that out before you post there.

Comment: [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) looks like a good target, depending on the scope of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask questions about using a specific program on [Super User](https://superuser.com/); see their ["What topics can I ask about here?" help page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking

If you have specific questions about *3D design*, your question could also be appropriate for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), which states on their [topics help page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward design professionals,
>   students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history;
> - Layout, printing and typography;
> - Color and composition;
> - The look & feel aspect of webdesign;
> - Illustration and image manipulation.

They have a specific [Sketchup](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketchup) tag for questions about that tool. Do take into account that *[a]pplication troubleshooting or technical support* is specifically off-topic however.

Read the linked on-topic help pages carefully and search the sites for prior questions that may cover what you want to know before posting.

Last but certainly not least, a [new *3D Graphics* site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics) is in the *Commitment* stage; I'm reasonably confident that Sketchup 3D modelling questions would be welcome there if the site were to open.

Comment: The Graphic Design topics page no longer lists 3D. We still get Sketchup questions so the recommendation is still valid but there is limited scope for answering 3D question on GD (there is however the [3D Graphics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics) that may be worth a mention).

Comment: @Cai: I had assumed that the person who edited in the Sketchup tag mention into this question had verified this. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The Sketchup tag is fine, it's the quote from the help page that is out of date (it was only relatively recently changed)

Comment: @Cai: thanks, post updated, including a mention of the new site proposal.